# Missing argument in python

Tags: python, arguments

Hello i'm new to programming and I have a problem with Python.
For a minesweeper I want to create a method in the class bomb in order to place bombs randomly in a array so that's what i wrote :

```
from random import randint

import numpy as np

a = np.zeros((9, 9), dtype="i")
print(a)

class bomb:
    def __init__(self, nb):
        self.nb = nb

    def init_bomb(self, nb):
        i = 0
        for i in range(0, nb):
            x = randint(0,8)
            y = randint(0,8)
            a[x,y] = 9


bomb.init_bomb(10)

print(a)
```

When i run the code i get this error :

> TypeError: init_bomb() missing 1 required positional argument: 'nb'

I don't understand why this nb because i wrote the nb that i want in between the parenthesis :

```
bomb.init_bomb(10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is trying to tell you that the `self` argument is missing.

The normal way to call a class method is to create an instance, then invoke the method on that instance:

```py
bombs = bomb(10)
bombs.init_bomb(10)
```

Conventionally, however, the `__init__` method should do all the necessary setup (and conventionally, the name of the class shoud be capitalized):

```py
class Bomb:
    def __init__(self, nb):
        self.nb = nb
        self.init_bomb()

    def init_bomb(self):
        # i = 0  # not necessary
        for i in range(0, self.nb):
            x = randint(0,8)
            y = randint(0,8)
            a[x,y] = 9
```

Notice also how `init_bomb` reads `self.nb`, so it only needs the `self` handle to access the `nb` attribute.

Now, you simply

```
bombs = Bomb(10)
```

(The global variable `a` should probably be a parameter, too.)

A class can define a `@staticmethod` which can and must be called without a `self` argument, but here, you probably want to manipulate a particular instance. (There's also `@classmethod` which defines a method whose first argument is the class itself.)

A more sensible design altogether would perhaps be `class Field` which you initialize with the size of the desired matrix and the number of bombs to place into it. It doesn't really make sense for `Bomb` to just have a number of bombs (in which case it should be plural `Bombs` anyway, shouldn't it?) and then promptly forget about where they are.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't initialise the `bomb` instance. Try this instead:

```py
from random import randint

import numpy as np

a = np.zeros((9, 9), dtype="i")
print(a)

class bomb:
    def __init__(self, nb):
        self.nb = nb

    def init_bomb(self):
        i = 0
        for i in range(0, self.nb):
            x = randint(0,8)
            y = randint(0,8)
            a[x,y] = 9


new_bomb = bomb(10)
new_bomb.init_bomb()

print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just call the initializer throught the class like this:

```
my_bomb = bomb(10)
```

remember to save it to a variable otherwise it will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

You Need To Initialize The Bomb Instance First

```
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros((9, 9), dtype="i")
print(a)

class bomb:
    def __init__(self, nb):
        self.nb = nb

    def init_bomb(self):
        i = 0
        for i in range(0, self.nb):
            x = randint(0,8)
            y = randint(0,8)
            a[x,y] = 9


new_bomb = bomb(10)
new_bomb.init_bomb()

print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

you haven't called the initializer
use a variable to initialize bomb class

```
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros((9, 9), dtype="i")
print(a)

class bomb:
   def __init__(self, nb):
    self.nb = nb

   def init_bomb(self):
    i = 0
    for i in range(0, self.nb):
        x = randint(0,8)
        y = randint(0,8)
        a[x,y] = 9


       new_bomb = bomb(10)
       new_bomb.init_bomb()
```